# Create PHP associative array using explode Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am a newbie in Codeigniter and created a form to input list of website from user where user either can insert website urls in a textarea separated by line or upload csv file contain a header named websites. I am using codeigniter library CSVReader to read data from csv and create an array like this:

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [websites] => www.google.com ) [1] => Array ( [websites] => www.bing.com ) )
```

while if I try to convert array from PHP explode function (if user input websites through textarea) Array looks like this:

```
Array(www.google.com,www.bing.com)
```

Code of my CSVReader is as:

```
<?php if (!defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class CSVReader {

var $fields;            /** columns names retrieved after parsing */ 
var $separator = ';';    /** separator used to explode each line */
var $enclosure = '"';    /** enclosure used to decorate each field */

var $max_row_size = 4096;    /** maximum row size to be used for decoding */

/**
 * Parse a file containing CSV formatted data.
 *
 * @access    public
 * @param    string
 * @param    boolean
 * @return    array
 */
function parse_file($p_Filepath, $p_NamedFields = true) {
    $content = false;
    $file = fopen($p_Filepath, 'r');
    if($p_NamedFields) {
        $this->fields = fgetcsv($file, $this->max_row_size, $this->separator, $this->enclosure);
    }
    while( ($row = fgetcsv($file, $this->max_row_size, $this->separator, $this->enclosure)) != false ) {  
        if( $row[0] != null ) { // skip empty lines
            if( !$content ) {
                $content = array();
            }
            if( $p_NamedFields ) {
                $items = array();

                // I prefer to fill the array with values of defined fields
                foreach( $this->fields as $id => $field ) {
                    if( isset($row[$id]) ) {
                        $items[$field] = $row[$id];    
                    }
                }
                $content[] = $items;
            } else {
                $content[] = $row;
            }
        }
    }
    fclose($file);
    return $content;
}
}
```

Could someone please help me create array in same styles?

Comment: What do you mean "array in same styles"? Can you give an example of the desired output array? Not sure if that's noted in your question.

Comment: There are 2 input options user can choose any CSV file upload or Textarea, my question is, I want to create an Array from both inputs and Array structure should be same. e.g Array('website1','website2');

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you need a whole big CSV reader to do that. Also, CSV is meant more for tabular data (if you had multiple columns of data), you're just building a flat list of websites - which greatly simplifies things. I would recommend something like this;

```
$websites = "foo,bar\nbaz,qux"; // Input
$output = preg_split('#[\n\r\t,]+#', $websites); // Split by newlines, feeds, tabs, and commas
foreach ($output as &$o)
   $o = array('website' => trim($o));

// Or a shorter form for PHP 5+
foreach ($output as &$o)
   $o = ['website' => trim($o)];
```

If you're getting the data from a form, you can completely strip out the CSV code unless you expect to be handling quotes or CSV file uploads. In that case, you only need one of the loops to make the array associative.

If the data is a multidimensional array of values you want to make associative, you can use the following loop (I made up the columns, they can be whatever you want):

```
// For PHP 4-
foreach ($output as &$o)
   $o = array(  'website' => $o[0], 'email' => $o[1], 'foo' => $o[2], 'bar'=>$o[3]  );

// Or a shorter form for PHP 5+
foreach ($output as &$o)
   $o = [  'website' => $o[0], 'email' => $o[1], 'foo' => $o[2], 'bar'=>$o[3]  ];
```

EDIT: Added trimming in first sample code.

Comment: Thanks Kver for your valuable time and well explanatory solution.

Answer (score 0):

You want both arrays to match, but you did not specify which style you want the arrays to end up in.

If you want to convert the CSV array do the following:

```
foreach($csv_array as $website) {
     $website_array[] = $website['websites'];
}
```

If you want to convert the textarea array do the following:

```
$count = 0;
foreach($textarea_input as $website) {
     $website_array[$count]['websites'] = $website;
     $count++;
}
```

I think the first one is easier to manage, there's not reason to add a second layer to your array, better to extract your data into a simpler array from the array that has multiple layers.

Comment: Thanks Dan for your time.